Why doesn't my code sort numbers greater than 128?
_start:
    mov rdx, len            ; Store the number of elements in rdx (len - 1)
    dec rdx                 ; Subtract 1 to get the index of the last element
    mov rsi, 0              ; Store the starting index (0) in rsi
    lea rdi, [array]        ; Load the address of the array into rdi
    call mergesort          ; Call the mergesort function

    call print_arr          ; Call the function to print the sorted array
    
    mov rax, 60             ; System call number for exit
    xor rdi, rdi            ; Exit status 0
    syscall

mergesort:
    cmp rsi, rdx            ; Compare the starting and ending indices
    jge _done               ; If starting index is greater than or equal to the ending index, exit
    push rbx                
    push rdx                ; Push the ending index onto the stack
    push rsi                ; Push the starting index onto the stack

    xor rbx, rbx            ; Initialize rbx to 0
    add rbx, rsi            ; Add the starting index to rbx
    add rbx, rdx            ; Add the ending index to rbx
    shr rbx, 1              ; Divide rbx by 2 to find the middle index

    mov rsi, rbx            ; Store the middle index in rsi
    inc rsi                 ; Move to the starting index of the right sub-array (mid + 1)
    call mergesort          ; Call mergesort for the right sub-array

    mov rdx, rbx            ; Store the middle index in rdx
    pop rsi                 ; Pop the starting index from the stack
    call mergesort          ; Call mergesort for the left sub-array

    pop rdx                 ; Pop the ending index from the stack
    mov rcx, rdx            ; Store the ending index in rcx
    mov rdx, rbx            ; Store the middle index in rdx
    call merge              ; Call the merge function

    pop rbx
_done:
    ret

merge:
    push r15
    push rcx                ; Push the ending index onto the stack
    push rdx                ; Push the middle index onto the stack
    push rsi                ; Push the starting index onto the stack

    mov r15, rsi            ; Store the starting index of the sorted array in r15
    mov r8, rsi             ; Store the starting index of the left sub-array in r8
    mov r9, rdx             ; Store the middle index in r9
    inc r9                  ; Move to the starting index of the right sub-array
    lea r10, [rdi + r8]     ; Load the address of the starting index of the left sub-array into r10
    lea r11, [rdi + r9]     ; Load the address of the starting index of the right sub-array into r11
    lea r12, [sorted + r15] ; Load the address of the starting index of the sorted array into r12
   
L1 : 
    cmp r8, rdx             ; Compare the left sub-array index with the middle index
    jg L4                   ; If the left sub-array index is greater than the middle index, jump to L4
    cmp r9, rcx             ; Compare the right sub-array index with the ending index
    jg L4                   ; If the right sub-array index is greater than the ending index, jump to L4
    
L5 : 
    mov al, byte [r11]     ; Move the byte at the right sub-array index into al
    cmp al, byte [r10]     ; Compare al with the byte at the left sub-array index
    jg L3                   ; If al is greater than the byte at the left sub-array index, jump to L3
    mov [r12], al           ; Move al into the sorted array
    inc r11                 ; Increment the right sub-array index
    inc r9                  ; Increment the right sub-array counter
    inc r15                 ; Increment the sorted array index
    inc r12                 ; Move to the next position in the sorted array
    jmp L1
    
L3 : 
    mov al, byte [r10]     ; Move the byte at the left sub-array index into al
    mov [r12], al           ; Move al into the sorted array
    inc r10                 ; Increment the left sub-array index
    inc r8                  ; Increment the left sub-array counter
    inc r15                 ; Increment the sorted array index
    inc r12                 ; Move to the next position in the sorted array
    jmp L1

L4 :
    cmp r8, rdx             ; Compare the left sub-array index with the middle index
    jle copyleft_1          ; If the left sub-array index is less than or equal to the middle index, jump to copyleft_1
    jmp copyright_1         ; Otherwise, jump to copyright_1

copyright_1 : 
    lea r13, [rdi+r9]      ; Load the address of the right sub-array index into r13
    
copyright_2 : 
    cmp r9, rcx             ; Compare the right sub-array index with the ending index
    jle copyright_3         ; If the right sub-array index is less than or equal to the ending index, jump to copyright_3
    jg fin

copyright_3 : 
    mov al, byte[r13]       ; Move the byte at the right sub-array index into al
    mov [r12], al           ; Move al into the sorted array
    inc r9                  ; Increment the right sub-array index
    inc r12                 ; Move to the next position in the sorted array
    inc r13                 ; Move to the next byte in the right sub-array
    jmp copyright_2

copyleft_1 : 
    lea r14, [rdi+r8]      ; Load the address of the left sub-array index into r14
    lea r12 ,[sorted +r15] ; Load the address of the sorted array index into r12
    
copyleft_2 :    
    cmp r8, rdx             ; Compare the left sub-array index with the middle index
    jle copyleft_3          ; If the left sub-array index is less than or equal to the middle index, jump to copyleft_3
    jg fin
    
copyleft_3 : 
    mov al, byte[r14]       ; Move the byte at the left sub-array index into al
    mov [r12], al           ; Move al into the sorted array
    inc r12                 ; Move to the next position in the sorted array
    inc r8                  ; Increment the left sub-array index
    inc r15                 ; Increment the sorted array index
    inc r13                 ; Move to the next byte in the left sub-array
    jmp copyleft_2

fin:
    lea r8, [rdi+rsi]       ; Load the address of the starting index of the left sub-array into r8
    lea r9, [sorted+rsi]    ; Load the address of the starting index of the sorted array into r9
    mov r10, rsi            ; Move the starting index of the sorted array into r10
    
movearray:
    mov al, byte [r9]       ; Move the byte from the sorted array into al
    mov [r8], al            ; Move al into the array
    inc r8                  ; Move to the next position in the array
    inc r9                  ; Move to the next position in the sorted array
    inc r10                 ; Increment the index counter
    cmp r10, rcx            ; Compare the index counter with the ending index
    jle movearray           ; If the index counter is less than or equal to the ending index, jump to movearray

    pop rsi                 ; Restore the values of the registers
    pop rdx
    pop rcx
    pop r15
    
    ret                     ; Return from the function

print_arr: 
    lea rsi, [array]        ; Load the address of the array into rsi
    mov rcx, len            ; Move the length of the array into rcx
    jmp print_loop          ; Jump to the print_loop label

print_loop:
    movzx r8d, byte[rsi]    ; Move the current element of the array into r8d
    printNumber r8d         ; Print the current element
    inc rsi                 ; Move to the next element in the array
    loop print_loop         ; Repeat until all elements are printed

    ret                     ; Return from the function


This code is for sorting numbers declared in an array using db. In my understanding, since db represents a 1-byte number, it should be able to sort any number between 0 and 255. However, when I actually insert numbers greater than 128 into the array, sorting doesn't occur, and the code breaks. I want to know why this problem occurs.
I want to know why this code can't sort numbers over 128. 8 bits number can express 0~255, but this code can't handle number over 128.

Use unsigned conditional branch instructions.  The signed branches are for signed bytes, whose values range from -128 to 127

You need to use an unsigned jump
    mov al, byte [r11]     ; Move the byte at the right sub-array index into al
    cmp al, byte [r10]     ; Compare al with the byte at the left sub-array index
    ja L3                  ; unsigned jump (jmp above)



I want to know why this code can't sort numbers over 128. 8 bits number can express 0~255, but this code can't handle number over 128. Plz help me.

If you decide to process byte-sized numbers in the range [0,255], then you have made the choice to deal with unsigned numbers. The x86 architecture has one set of conditional branch instructions for signed numbers, and another set of conditional branch instructions for unsigned numbers.

mov al, byte [r11]     ; Move the byte at the right sub-array index into al
cmp al, byte [r10]     ; Compare al with the byte at the left sub-array index
jg L3                  ; If al is greater than the byte at the left sub-array index, jump to L3


In your code you are using jg after comparing array elements. The jg conditional branch instruction (JumpIfGreater) is meant to be used with signed numbers! For your unsigned numbers use case, you need to write the ja instruction (JumpIfAbove).
The same applies to your dealing with the array indexes. Those too are basically unsigned numbers, so you should use the appropiate instructions: ja, jae, jb, jbe, jna, jnae, jnb, jnbe.
See Assembly: Difference between JNA and JL for a similar case of signed vs unsigned.

Though pointers are necessarily unsigned, array indexes are not necessarily unsigned — that's more programmer/application choice with the consideration that signed types have less range by 1 bit.

@ErikEidt - are there any operating systems that have the sign bit set on 64 bit pointers for some operating system related stuff?

@rcgldr, I don't know any but it is theoretically possible and does happen on 32-bit systems.  There are some physical memory mappings that place memory mapped I/O at "negative" addresses for 64-bit systems.
